# Sending email from Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7 application I want to send an e-mail where the message body should contain the data from my previous page in my application. Previously I just integrated the e-mail facility like this:

```
private void Image_Email(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

    emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
    emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
    emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
    emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
    emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";
    emailComposeTask.Show();
}
```

But I was not able to test this in my emulator. Now in the `body` part I want my data from the previous page. So how to do this?

Updated code:

```
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Date_Start"))
{
    //if it is available, get parameter value
    date = NavigationContext.QueryString["Date_Start"];
    datee.Text = date;
}

if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Title"))
{
    //if it is available, get parameter value
    ntitle = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Title"];
    title.Text = ntitle;
}

if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("News_Description"))
{
    ndes = NavigationContext.QueryString["News_Description"];
    description.Text = ndes;
}
```

Now what do I write in the message body? I am not able to test it as I do not have a device.
Can i pass in the values like this:

```
emailComposeTask.Body = "title, ndes, date";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is correct. if you want to pass body from previous page, you need to pass it when page navigation. and set emailComposeTask.Body = yourPassedValue.
like this:

```
var date;
var title;
var ndes;

emailComposeTask.Body = title + "," + ndes + "," + date;
```

Comment: Please see my updated code. Is this the way to write it?

Comment: Hi,I have answered your new question about SMS. Please read it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your message body line like this:

```
emailComposeTask.Body = title+" "+ ndes+" "+ date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test sending mail in the emulator since you don't have a proper email account set up. Nor you could set it up in the emulator.

The `Body` property is a string so you can put inside pretty much anything you want.

Using the following code will only generate a string containing exactly that:

```
emailComposeTask.Body = "title, ndes, date";
```

So the result mail will have a body containing "title, ndes, date" as a text. If you want to replace the title with the value from the local variable named `title`, you need to use the following syntax:

```
emailComposeTask.Body = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", title, nodes, date);
```